# Checking for valid directory name with absolute path in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, pattern-matching

How can I check that if the given string is a valid directory name or not in Unix . I am looking to verify that the string is a valid absolute path [Not necessary that the path is already existing . I basically want to store this value after verification into a configuration file and create this path later if necessary with mkdir -p ${DIR_NAME} ] .

ex : The below are valid

```
/test/dir1/dir2
/test/dir1/dir2/
```

ex: below are invalid

```
test/dir1
test//dir1
```

I can check if it's directory or not like

```
test -d ${DIR_NAME}
```

But it will return true if the directory exists . In my case even though the directory is not there I want to just make sure that the DIR_NAME passed is a valid value .

how can I achieve this ?

Comment: An absolute path starts with a slash.

Comment: @n.m. Yes.. But how can I check for the entire string if it is a valid directory name

Comment: It is valid if it is (1) absolute and (2) exists.

Comment: For my requirement is doesn't have to be a existing path . Only requirement is ,it has to be a proper directory path . If it is correct then I will store this in some configuration file and checks and creates it later ,if necessary

Comment: And basically I am looking for a regular expression kind of answer or if there any existing command for the same ,that is also fine for me

Comment: Any string that starts with a `/` can potentially be an absolute path. `if [[ ${DIR_NAME} == /* ]]; then ...`

Comment: for resolving whether an unknown relative path is valid, use the `readlink -f` command. e.g. `readlink -f "test/dir1"` will return the full-path for the directories which you can then parse, test, etc.